# Placing the svg content within an element

Tags: snap.svg

I'm using the following syntax to create the svg element:

```
var s = Snap(stage_width,stage_height);
```

This places the svg in the body, but what if I needed the svg element in a container of my choice. Is there a way to specify which element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own svg element in html and have Snap use that as the container.

```
<svg id="put_it_here"></svg>
...
var s = Snap("#put_it_here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have :

```
    var s = Snap("#g8");

    g8.attr({

    "id": "g8"

    })
```

And you can make groups and name them and add any elements to the group as well. And if you need the element/group markup without the svg container you can use:

```
console.log( element.toString()); // to have the markup for an element or group
```

And if you need the svg container(snap paper) markup use:

```
console.log( s.toString());// to have the markup for an svg
```

So, you can name your container whatever you want programatically and this would be added to your svg/group/element markup.

Edit: if your svg file is external and want to load them into an element of your choice you can use snap.ajax.